# How to reset and remove the Java language support which I had added for VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I had added support for Java in VS Code . I no longer need it so I want to remove the support and take my VS Code to the state it was before.

Comment: If you added support for Java using VS Code extensions, click on the extensions tab and uninstall or disable all the extensions related to Java.

Comment: What specific problems are you having removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After backing up settings about other languages, you can delete the follwoing folders to reset VS Code. Then install other needed extensions.

> **Windows** - Delete `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`.
> **macOS** - Delete `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode`.
> **Linux** - Delete `$HOME/.config/Code` and `~/.vscode`.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall it from the command line. From the registry (regedit). Open the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Select the Uninstall key and "Find" from the "Edit" menu. Search for "Java." This will show you which subkey the Java is located under. Identify the "UninstallString." keystring. Use this command to uninstall Java.